# onchange for select button

Tags: jquery, onchange

I need to catch the unsaved changed. I have this problem: If only one row is entered and there is no other event such as tab or mouse click, onchange is not working for browser navigation e.g. Scenario 1: Enter a number and then use browser buttons. If it is select box then Scenario 2: Select a item through the keyboard navigation (up/down arrow) and then use browser buttons.  It does not work.

My jquery code is,

```
$(':input', document.frmName).live("change", function(e) { alert ('Modified'); });
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `change` event doesn't fire until the focus leaves the control, which as you've observed may be too late in your case.

The usual approach when you need really proactive notification is to use a combination of various events — `keydown`, `keypress`, `click` — combined with a polling timer (to handle things for which no event is raised reliably cross-browser, like right-click followed by pasting from the context menu).